# Ant build XML not copying .so files

Tags: java, xml, ant, arm

I'm trying to run a copy command within an Ant build XML file to build some 3rd party software from source. I've tried this command numerous ways with various results.

**Attempt 1 (out of the box):**

```
<copy file="${result.grep_out}" tofile="${build.libpcap.so}" />
```

This fails with the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/pi/myDir/build.xml:612: Use a resource collection to copy directories.
```

So it seems like ".so" files (which is being copied in this case) is considered a *special* file, and so cannot be treated like a normal file.

**Attempt 2:**

```
<copy todir="${build.libpcap.so}">
    <fileset dir="${result.grep_out}" />
</copy>
```

This didn't cause the build to fail on this line, but it did cause problems later as the .so file being copied took the form of a dir, not a file at all, and so was rendered useless.

**Attempt 3:**

Changing it to:

```
<copy tofile="${build.libpcap.so}">
    <fileset dir="${result.grep_out}" />
</copy>
```

Yielded the following error

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/pi/myDir/build.xml:612: Cannot concatenate multiple files into a single file.
```

This makes sense, as I've told it to copy what I said was a dir to a file.

**Attempt 4**

And finally

```
<copy file="${result.grep_out}" todir="${build.libpcap.so}" />
```

Fails with the first error again.

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/pi/myDir/build.xml:612: Use a resource collection to copy directories.
```

I'm trying to do this on an ARM processor, and the code being built is jNetPcap, if that matters.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

The preceding code, I think, holds some clues about this.

```
<exec executable="locate" outproperty="result.locate_out" >
    <arg value="libpcap.so"/>
</exec>

<exec executable="grep" inputstring="${result.locate_out}" outputproperty="result.grep_out">
    <arg value="libpcap.so$" />
</exec>

<!-- then the copy code i mentioned earlier. -->
```

Printing out the output shows me that the first "locate" command has no output, which seems to be causing the problem. "locate", when run manually from my command line, also has no output though libpcap.so does exist on my computer. So some issue with this command or how I'm running it seems to be causing the problem.

Comment: What is the value of `result.grep_out`?  I suspect you're getting multiple files there rather than the single .so you're expecting.

Comment: Ah! it was empty. Tracing back through the build file I think I found a reason for this... updating my question.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! @Brian helped me see that ${result.grep_out} was actually empty as a previous command had failed.

The "locate" command this depended on (as seen in the question) wasn't returning anything as updatedb hadn't been run since installing the ".so" file it was looking for.

Simply using the original copy syntax and running "updatedb" on the command line did the trick!